# Semantic-ui checkbox onChange event not triggered

Tags: checkbox, onchange, semantic-ui, reactjs

I am trying to change the state of a checkbox:

```
var React = require('react');

var UserTable = React.createClass({

  handleCheckboxChange: function(field) {
    return function(e) {
      var value = !e.target.checked;
      // this updates the state in the parent module
      this.props.onUserUpdate(field, value);
      // this persists the state to the server
      this.props.onUserSave(field);
    }.bind(this);
  },


  render: function() {
    var user = this.props.data;
    return (
      <div className="ui toggle checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange("topup_enabled")} checked={user.topup_enabled} />
        <label></label>
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

Debugging this, I see that `handleCheckboxChange` is never being called.

Any idea why ?

**EDIT**

As pointed by @nilgun, react's code should actually work, the problem is that I am somehow misusing [semantic-ui checkbox](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html).

See this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zza2furx/1/

Comment: Actually it is called, see the console log: http://jsfiddle.net/zza2furx/

Comment: @nilgun you are right! apparently the problem is with [semantic-ui's checkbox](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html). removing the class definition `ui toggle checkbox` solves the problem. your jsfiddle, which did not contain semantic-ui css/js and hence did not hae the problem, helped me realize it. thanks !

Comment: Also your event handler looks a little confusing. You can simplify it by using key="topup_enabled" and retrieve it from `event.dispatchMarker.split('.')`.

Comment: please see this updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zza2furx/1/

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be resolved with :

```js
var MyCheckBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            checked:false
        }
    },

    handleChange: function(event) {
        this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="ui toggle checkbox" onClick={this.handleChange} />
                <input type="checkbox" value={this.state.checked} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```